# Lucene: Get Field with most impact on Document Score

Tags: c#, lucene.net

I have a MultiFieldQueryParser with multiple fields defined e.g. CarName, Vendor, Power, ... and for the search result I want to display only the field which has impacted the score the most. So for example if I search for BMW I want to only display the Vendor and not CarName or Power.
Is there a way to achieve that, I can only get the document score.
Note: I'm very new to Lucene